# Need clarification on Rest API response design

Tags: node.js, api

We have an REST API that need to be consume from our end. Lets says

```
URL: https://domain/method/param
header:
{Authorization:'' }
```

Now, the response of the rest api is in json array as below:

```
[{"a": 1, "b": 2}]
```

My query:

1. Is the above format of response is correct (which I doubt)?
2. Because I am not able to get the data even though the API is returning with `200` status code. So, is it the issue with API or something to do in my code. I am just simply using request api of node js to consume this service.

In my view the response should be a single JSON object like:

```
{data :[{"a": 1, "b": 2}]}
```

So, for more understanding I am adding the screenshot of response in my code and through postman.

[image: response when hitting through code]

[image: response when hitting through postman]

Comment: Is it a get request? i think response is correct if you are sending it as array of object, you can set "Content-Type: application/json", please upload a sample code so we can have a look on it.

Comment: @DevProf  updated my query.

Answer (score 1):

There is no fix response or error JSON objects, but as per your comfort you can create your own.

Here below i'm showing you my response and error objects that i use while developing rest APIs

> Success Response object

```
 {
   "code" : 200, (any success code 201,301)
   "data" : object or array 
 }
```

> Error Response object

```
 {
   "code" : 404, (any error code 400,422,500)
   "error" : "error message"
 }
```

Here i have took code, you can also you status which will be true or false.

Comment: I know thats what the default response behavior of any API. But my query is, is it possible to have only a response array as I showed in snapshot and can we consume the API and get the data?

Comment: Yes you can consume those API there is nothing wrong with it, but for good code/developing purpose you shouldn't use those kind of response. If there is third party response then definitely you can go ahead with that.

Comment: Why do we have to include the status code? Isn't the status code already provided in the http protocol?

Comment: This is if you want to send your own error code, when you are developing an API or something.

Answer (score 0):

JSON only returns as JSON, so the array itself is going to be paired like you have in your second view. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: so, thats not what happening when I am hitting the URL through postman. Please see the query again I have updated it with screenshots.